# pg_dump fails to dump specific schema

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, pg-dump

I am using `pg_dump` (15.3) to dump information on a database.

This command works:
`pg_dump --schema-only --schema foo -d foodb -U postgres -Fp` and dumps among other things a `CREATE SCHEMA foo;` statement

This command doesn't:
`pg_dump --schema-only --schema cron -d foodb -U postgres -Fp` since it only dumps the following:

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Note that it doesn't complain that the schema does not exist.

`SELECT a.* FROM information_schema.schemata a where schema_name in ('foo','cron');`

shows the same output (apart from the `schema_name`) for both schemata

I am using a timescaledb (timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg15.3-ts2.11.0-all) from Docker if this is of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schemas created as part of an extension will not get dumped by the command you show, giving the symptoms you show.  cron is probably created by the extension pg_cron.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command if your pg_dump is not dumping the cron schema;

```
pg_dump --schema=cron -d yourdatabase -U postgres -Fp -f cron_schema_dump.sql
```

Replace yourdatabase with the name of your actual database.